# iPhone : Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, ios4, core-graphics

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I use this method to draw image. But something in the code seems to not be released properly because every-time I call a this method and my application memory footprint increases.

Here,I am providing method which increase my memory.

```
-(void)imagemaking
{
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

statuses = [parser objectWithString:responseString
                              error:nil];
[parser release];


networkConnection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NetworkTrans1.png"];


[updateTimeClock setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenClock.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSArray *segment = [[NSArray alloc]init];
segment = [statuses valueForKey:@"Segments"];

int linewidth = 3;

CGSize polyimagesize = CGSizeMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width , self.mapView.frame.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(polyimagesize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, linewidth);

CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.6);    

for(NSDictionary *route in segment) {

    NSString *locations = [route valueForKey:@"Locations"];

    if (locations && ([locations length]/16 > 1)) {       

        UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

        for (int i = 0; i <= locations.length - 32; i += 32) {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
            coordinates.latitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 16)]);
            coordinates.longitude = hexDecode_iPhone([locations substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i+16, 16)]);

            CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:coordinates toPointToView:self.mapView];

            if (i == 0)
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
            else
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }

        CGContextStrokePath(context);

    }        
}       

madeimage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[responseString release];   
[segment release];
```

}

As per my Investigation,Memory foot print increase because of CoreGraphics.But i don't know how to reduce memory usage or which object is increase the memory usage.Please provide guide-line  .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning [statuses valueForKey:@"Segments"]; to segment and loosing address previously allocated by [[NSArray alloc]init];

```
NSArray *segment = [[NSArray alloc]init]; //Array #1
segment = [statuses valueForKey:@"Segments"]; //Array #2 (replaces #1)
```

Final release is not aware of previously allocated memory address; it can only release array #2.

```
[segment release];
```

So the statement that causes the first array to be leaked is at:

```
segment = [statuses valueForKey:@"Segments"];
```

Comment: I think, First you should go through whole code.I release segment at the end of function.I have check whole 10 times with help of instruments and i found that there is no leak in my application.

Comment: You are releasing something else.

Comment: @Nit: You are releasing the array returned by `valueForKey:`, but not the array returned by `alloc` and `init`. They are two separate array objects, and you immediately replace the first one with the second and thereby leak the first. Even if there is another leak (and if there is, I can't see it in the code you showed), jacekmigacz's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

take a temporary array and assign it to your segment array

NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];

NSArray *segment=tempArray;

segment = [statuses valueForKey:@"Segments"];

[tempArray release];

This will remove the memory leak being caused by segmentarray.

Comment: i know that you have already released segment array but try doing the tempArray thing.It will surely remove the memory leak.just give it a try